# Why does the size of the contents of a <button> tag change its position?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out why my buttons aren't lining up, and I figured out it's because the size of their contents are different.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ktjboox3/

```css
button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  hello
</button>
<button>
  hello <br />
  hello
</button>
<button>
  hello <br />
  hello <br />
  hello
</button>
```

You can see that the buttons with more content have this strange top-margin-but-not-actually-margin going on. Why are they layed out lower? It appears to be a requirement that they all have a set width and height, but I need all my buttons to be the same size.

And to be clear, even though I am certainly interested in getting my code to work, the actual answer I'm looking for isn't a code snippet where the buttons are all lined up, I want to understand this is happening in the first place.

Comment: are you using a css framework?

Comment: Interesting question, and yes it is easy to fix the alignment, but understanding the reason why this occurs is puzzling. I hope you only accept the answer to your actual question and not suggestions on how to fix it. I'm really interested in finding this out myself.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Bootstrap 3, but I was able to reproduce the behavior in that fiddle without any CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look carefully you will notice that the baselines of all three buttons (the bottom of the last line) (Chrome might have got this wrong) are vertically aligned. This is the expected behavior since the initial value for [**`vertical-align`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property is ***baseline***.

To align the top of all buttons, set the vertical align to top.

```css
button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<button>
  hello
</button>
<button>
  hello<br>
  hello
</button>
<button>
  hello<br>
  hello<br>
  hello
</button>
```

Comment: Good observation, I never noticed that before. But I still don't understand why it would shift the parent container's position. Anyway, this is the closest answer to the question. The others are just showing how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining it! I guess I didn't understand what vertical-align does. This was illuminating, thanks again.

Comment: @GeneParcellano think of it as having three words on one line where each word has different font-size. Their baselines must be aligned together and therefore the shorter words must be pushed downwards. See http://jsfiddle.net/wnhcnxku/

Answer (score 5):

```css
button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  vertical-align: top;/* or middle/bottom/... whatever suits your needs best */
}
```

```html
<button>hello</button>
<button>hello
  <br />hello</button>
<button>hello
  <br />hello
  <br />hello</button>
```

buttons are inline-block element and can be set on the same level from the base line with: `vertical-align`

https://jsfiddle.net/ktjboox3/5/